# smooth scrolling offset not working on iOS Safari

Tags: jquery, scrollview, mobile-safari, offset, smooth-scrolling

I am using this code, works well on Safari and Firefox and adapts perfectly when resizing the browser window and the mobile navigation appears. In both cases all sections scroll and align with their offset (which is 140px on desktop and 60px on mobile).

But on iOS Safari the links do not respect the offset... am I missing something on the code?

Thanks

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var offset = 0;
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if ($(this).data('offset') != undefined) offset = $(this).data('offset');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - offset
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

HTML links are all like this (data-offset="60" on mobile nav):

```
<li><a id="link2" href="#page-section-60fd24e9182d15129d52aeec" data-offset="140">Programs</a></li>
```